# Camera along a curve with geometry nodes

Tags: animation, camera, geometry-nodes

I want to set the position and direction according to the curve I made at the geometry nodes.
I gave an example of how this is supposed to be
[image: Camera along a curve]

---

I extracted values to the camera location. I can't connect them to the camera values.

[image: output from geo nodes]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way I did it is by using constraints in the camera, and vertex groups on the mesh with the geometry nodes

to do the tracking I nudge the factor on the factor, the lower the factor is the bumpier it gets.

for the camera is I did a copy location and track to the corresponding vertex groups

NOTE: It can't be a cyclic curve, because it will point downwards at the end
[image: node setup]

I'll share the blender file because it's a bit confusing

[image]

Comment: I still did'nt understand exactly how, but it works great. I'll study this in depth later. Thank you very much

Comment: all it is, is just constraint copy location on one vertex, and track to to the nudged vertex

Comment: How did you preserve the vertex? I cannot get the camera to follow an object that is on a geometry nodes path because the instance looses the vertex group :(

Comment: Beautiful solution thank you! In your project everything works but when I'm trying to recreate it in my project (nothing else in it) I'm having problems connecting Trk point to nudge point. 
Any chance you can explain how you connected vertex groups to Trk and Loc?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

There is an interesting solution: how to bind the camera to the single point generated by Geometry Nodes. Use Shrinkwrap Constraint to bind a camera to the single point on geometry. Also use Shrinkwrap Constraint to bind an empty object to the linked copy of geometry but with the step. Align Camera to this empty object using the Constraints.

Answer (score 0):

You can use follow path constraint for that:

[image]

This is not the geometry nodes, of course, but you can't modify values outside the object in geometry nodes.

Comment: The curve moves with animation. So that can not be a solution.
Thank you