In geometry nodes, how do you rotate the camera while it's following a curve path?
I have a camera following a curve, using the sample curve node. I can animate the movement of the camera using the factor of the sample curve. But,how do I rotate the camera relative to its position in the curve?


Have you tried https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/263736/ or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/283794/ ?

I'm a little confused... what is "camera" in your setup? The cube? Is your question about how to rotate the cube (which does not address the camera issue) or is your question about how to "actually" move the camera?

To control the camera in geometry nodes, I had to link it to a mesh. So, yes, the cube and the camera is one and the same.

Do you want the axis of the camera to be aligned with the curve tangent ?

Yes, that is actually what I wanted to ask for. I don't want the camera(cube) to face a constant direction while it's moving along the curve.
